# react-beautiful-dnd. Как определить над каким элементом (Draggable) был сброшен элемент

Tags: reactjs

react-beautiful-dnd. Как определить над каким элементом (Draggable находящемся в Droppble) был сброшен перетаскиваемый элемент. Функция onDragEnd не дает такой информации...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сразу скажу, что данной библиотекой не пользовался и мой ответ будет сильно абстрактным, но скорее всего вам подойдет вариант с отслеживанием рефа. Попробуйте подключить реф к компонентам DragDropContext или Droppable. Внутри них с высокой долей вероятности будет содержимое в лице Draggable компонентов. На событие onDragEnd вы можете вызывать функцию, которая найдет элемент с которым вы отработали и проверит, какой элемент находится после нее.